# Set Outlook Default Signature through Remote Session

Tags: powershell, outlook, powershell-2.0

i hope that someone got an Idea how i can fix the following problem.

We have XP and Win7 clients in our company.
The clients have Office 2003, Office XP and Office 2010.

### A Question first:

Is it possible to add an .ps1 startup script on Windows XP?
Maybe with: %SystemRoot%\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe script.ps1
Executionpolicy on the Clients: Remotesigned (No Cert available!)

If 1 is possible:
Copy the content of \Servername\Netlogon\OutlookSignature\%Username%_CompanySigFolder Path into the following Path C:\Users\%Username%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Signatures\DefaultCompanySignatureName

If 1 is not possible:
I will run a normal .cmd Startup Script 1 day before that copies the Files to %appdata%....

### Now the real question:

After the files are copied, **is it possible to set the new Signature to the Users Default Outlook  Signature?** 
I have read that it might go via registry entry, but found no detailed information.

I got full access through PS-Remoting to all Computers in the Domain.
Will this work, if an Outlook Session is active?

The Script must distinguish between XP an Win7 an then between Office XP,2003 and 2010.

Thanks in Advance!
Daniel

Comment: I've gone off track reading this, but if you want to change some settings in Outlook, you can have a look at creating an Outlook COM object in Powershell, and then can script the changes you want to make in the Outlook client.

Comment: You´ve gone off reading this? Is it due to the translation? I´m sorry. I´m from Germany, my english is not so good. :/

Comment: To illustrate what I'm saying, here's a code example that will create an outlook email and send it.
I know you don't want to create and send an e-mail, but my point is that you can use the Outlook COM interface to script manual tasks.
$Outlook = New-Object -ComObject Outlook.Application
$OutlookMessage = $Outlook.CreateItem(0)
$OutlookMessage.To = "test@test.com"
$OutlookMessage.Subject = "Message"
$OutlookMessage.HTMLBody = "HTML Text"
$OutlookMessage.Attachments.Add("C:\test.pdf")
$OutlookMessage.ReadReceiptRequested = $true

Comment: Hi, i have solved it by a cmd script. I´ve found the Registry Key´s to the outlook signature and deploy them through a GPO Script. [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\11.0\Common\MailSettings]thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#Set the signature as default for new emails
$MSWord = New-Object -ComObject word.application
$EmailOptions = $MSWord.EmailOptions
$EmailSignature = $EmailOptions.EmailSignature
$EmailSignature.NewMessageSignature = “name of signature” #insert the signature name
$MSWord.Quit()
```